# Type error; 'MessageEmbed" of undefined in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots, embed

I cant understand why i am getting the error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'MessageEmbed' of undefined

Here is my code:

```
module.exports = {
name: 'help',
description: "this is the help command",
execute(message, args, Discord){
  const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#304281')
  .setTitle('Commands')
  .setDescription('here are the commands'),
  .addFields(
    {name: '-help', value: 'The help command'},
    {name: '-ping', value: 'Ping pong**'}
  ),
  .setFooter('thanks for using the bot')

  message.channel.send(newEmbed);
```

Comment: It might be that you are not passing in Discord to your command correctly? More code may be needed to answer this question

Comment: What more code is needed?

Comment: This is the code in my main.js file:     if(command === 'help'){
        client.commands.get('help').execute(message,args)

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed by adding a little code:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
  const newEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
```

after i did this it worked

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you are calling your code with:

```js
// 2 arguments passed
client.commands.get('help').execute(message,args)
```

However, your command takes 3 arguments:

```js
execute(message, args, Discord){
  // ...
}
```

Thus, `Discord` is `undefined`, causing your errors. To fix this you can:

- Pass `Discord` when executing the command

  ```js
  client.commands.get("help").execute(message, args, Discord);
  ```
- `const Discord = require("discord.js")` inside of your command

  ```js
  const Discord = require("discord.js");
  // ...
  execute(message, args){
    const newEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
    // ...
  ```